# Synchronous http get call with for loop in Angular js ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I need a situation to be handle where I need a loop to execute multiple times for http get call. Here is my code

```
   for(i = 1; i <= 5; i++){
    console.log(i);
    var req = {
         method: 'GET',
         timeout: 30000,
         url: url
         params: {page_id: i}
      };
      $http(req).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          console.log(data);
      }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          console.log('error');
      });      
   }
```

I need this to handle but not getting the values in order.

Answer (score 1):

Use a function call in your loop, sample below:

```
function httpRequestFn(req) {
    $http(req).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log(data);
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log('error');
    });
}

for(i = 1; i <= 5; i++){
    console.log(i);
    var req = {
        method: 'GET',
        timeout: 30000,
        url: url
        params: {page_id: i}
    };
    httpRequestFn(req);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to send multiple request one shot then i would suggest to use the `$q.all`

```
var httpArr = [];
for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    console.log(i);
    var req = {
        method: 'GET',
        timeout: 30000,
        url: url
        params: {
            page_id: i
        }
    };
    httpArr.push($http(req))
}
$q.all(httpArr).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response[0].data) // 1st request response 
    console.log(response[1].data) // 2nd request response 
    console.log(response[2].data) // 3rd request response 
}).catch(function(response) {
    //error resonse
})
```

Make sure to inject `$q` to controller